# How to make a flexbox that expands on hover to have a scroll option on mobile? Example for what I'm looking for included

Tags: css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I have a banner that has 5 pictures side by side in which each on expands to display the text more upon hover. However on mobile it becomes very difficult to read so I was wondering if there was a way to add a scrolling effect like the Foo Fighters site ( https://foofighters.com/ )

I'm trying to avoid having a scroll bar and have left and right arrow instead.

The site is built on bootstrap 4.

```css
#container-banner {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 75vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

#container-banner:hover>.section {
  -webkit-filter: brightness(22%);
  filter: brightness(22%);
}

#container-banner:hover>.section:hover {
  -webkit-filter: brightness(100%);
  filter: brightness(100%);
}

#container-banner .section {
  flex-grow: 1;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 0.4s;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  flex: 1;
}

#container-banner .section .cont_title {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 37vh;
}

#container-banner .section .cont_title h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Economica', sans-serif;
  text-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  font-size: 3.5vw;
  margin: 0;
  transition: font-size 0.3s;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#container-banner .section .cont_title h3 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Economica', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.3vw;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  color: white;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  text-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#container-banner .section .cont_desc {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 12vw;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.8s, padding-top 0.9s, -webkit-transform 0.7s;
  transition: opacity 0.8s, transform 0.7s, padding-top 0.9s;
  transition: opacity 0.8s, transform 0.7s, padding-top 0.9s, -webkit-transform 0.7s;
  padding-top: 6vh;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}

#container-banner .section .cont_desc p {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Economica', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#container-banner .section:hover {
  flex-grow: 1.8;
  transition: flex 0.2s;
}

#container-banner .section:hover>.cont_title h1 {
  font-size: 5.3vw;
  transition: font-size 0.4s;
}

#container-banner .section:hover>.cont_title h3 {
  font-size: 1.6vw;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}

#container-banner .section:hover>.cont_desc {
  opacity: 1;
  padding-top: 2vh;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
  transform: scale(1.5);
  transition: opacity 0.7s, padding-top 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.1s;
  transition: opacity 0.7s, padding-top 0.5s, transform 0.1s;
  transition: opacity 0.7s, padding-top 0.5s, transform 0.1s, -webkit-transform 0.1s;
  transition-delay: 0s, 0.1s, 0s;
}

#container-banner .section:nth-child(1) {
  background: url("../img/members/2nd-round.jpg") center;
}

#container-banner .section:nth-child(2) {
  background: url("../img/members/3rd-round.jpg") center;
}

#container-banner .section:nth-child(3) {
  background: url("../img/HRBAlbumCover.svg") center;
  object-fit: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: contain;
  background-size: contain;
  background-color: black;
}

#container-banner .section:nth-child(4) {
  background: url("../img/members/3.jpg") center;
}

#container-banner .section:nth-child(5) {
  background: url("../img/members/4.jpg") center;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<section id="container-banner">
  <div class="section first">
    <div class="cont_title">
      <h1><a href="music.html">Music</a></h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="section">
    <div class="cont_title">
      <h1><a href="tour.html">Tour</a></h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="section">
    <div class="cont_title">
      <h1 class="font-weight-bold">Members<br>Only</h1>
      <h3>Free Song<br>upon Sign-Up</h3>
      <button class="btn hoverable">Sign-Up</button>
      <button class="btn hoverable">Sign-In</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="section">
    <div class="cont_title">
      <h1><a href="https://www.LinkToTheSite.com">Store</a></h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="section">
    <div class="cont_title">
      <h1><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you used a jquery library called `owl.carousel`: https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2? It's an awesome library to let you easily create carousel slider that supports touch and drag, which is crucial in mobile devices.

#### On small devices

[image]

#### wider than 600px

[image]

#### wider than 1000px

[image]

And you can totally customize how many items you want to display per each break point:

```
$(function(){
    $("#banner").owlCarousel({
    loop: true,
    margin: 10,
    nav: true,
    responsive: {
        0: {
        items: 2
      },
      600: {
        items: 3
      },
      1000: {
        items: 5
      }
    }
  });
});
```

The navigation arrows could have been given more loves but you can totally style them however you want.

Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/324749/

Comment: Hi @David,  I have used it before but I was trying to avoid using it this time because I always end up with a lot of css and js added to the websites and things start getting cluttered. But, I had forgotten about the swiping motion on mobile so going with owl carousel may be the best option since idk any other way around it. Thank you for taking the time in helping me out :)